# Declaring Property of Multiple Elements in An Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, variable-declaration

So when initializing an array you can use:

```
Dim array(0 to 9) As Integer
```

What i would like to do is be able to then declare the values like this:

```
array(0 to 4) = 1
```

But this errors out. So is there any short simple way to do this without having to write a declaring line for each element like this:

```
array(0) = 1
array(1) = 1
array(2) = 1
array(3) = 1
array(4) = 1
```

This is just a general inquire if syntax exists to simplify such a procedure.
My specific need is roughly this:

```
Sub test()
Dim cb(0 to 74) As CheckBox
Dim I As Integer
For I = 0 To UBound(cb)
    cb(I) = Worksheets("SheetName").CheckBoxes(I)
Next I
cb(0 to 6).Enabled = True
cb(7 to 74).Enabled = False
End Sub
```

I'll be using this code to enable/disable different check box groups on a form, and i'd much rather not have to declare all 75 individually each time.

Comment: FYI: `Dim array` is a compile error.

Comment: yeah, it was just a generalizer for whatever array name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop is necessary, but just handle the boolean evaluation at the time you instantiate your object array:

```
For I = 0 To UBound(cb)
    Set cb(I) = Worksheets("SheetName").CheckBoxes(I)
    cb(I).Enabled = (I <= 6)
Next I
```

Actually from the example, you don't need an array at all:

```
Sub test()

Dim I As Integer
For I = 0 To 74
    Worksheets("SheetName").CheckBoxes(I).Enabled = (I <=6)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Most excellent, how foolish of me to overlook such a simple solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No avoiding a loop I don't think

```
for i=0 to 4
  array(i)=1
next i
```

Comment: A for loop is small and simple enough, it's likely what i'll have to do.
I just wish vb was more flexible with its syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Dim is as a variant, and then assign an array to it like this:

```
Dim a As Variant
a = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```